# separate the view in type of user with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am making a project and the table Users haver a column called "tipo de usuario" (type of user in spanish) so I need that one kind of user (client) can't acces to some views that the other user (staff) does, in laravel I am using this in my controllers:

```
public function __construct(){

    $this->middleware('auth');

}
```

That is working so only logged users can acces, but then if a client try to acces to a view that should be only for my staff then he can do it because they both are logged users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have different roles for the users.

You can create another middleware using the artisan command:

```
php artisan make:middleware <name>
```

Then, on the handle method, you can check the role of the user

Something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->role !== 'staff') {
        // Response if not staff
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Don't forget to register the middleware on the kernel (app/http/)

Comment: ok, i have a few questions about the middleware:
1. Do I need to create a middleware for every single role?
2. how do I use that middleware in the constructor of a controller?
3. How do I register the middleware on the kernel?
Thanks for the help

Comment: 1. I think so. At least, it will be easier. 2. You can add the same has any other middleware so $this->middleware(<name of the middleware>). 3. On the kernel.php file (App/Http/), you just add it on the routeMiddleware. You can find more about middleware on laravel documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware